# SQL Server Multiple Replacements

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, performance, replace

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 - 2016. I have inherited a function we use to make friendly urls - i.e. multiple character replacements. I've just opened it and the code seems "less than optimal".

It works, and everything in here has a good reason to be there, although some of the replacements look a bit odd. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient option for implementing the repeated replacements.

I know you can nest them one inside another, but with this many replacements that is going to be as ugly as sin. I could push them into a table and loop through that but I can just imagine the efficiency hit we'd take. Does anyone have a better way of doing these replacements? I look at the code and I'm convinced there has to be a better option, but I don't know what.

Any options gratefully received.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MakeFriendlyURL (@stringToConvert NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @Result = CAST(@stringToConvert AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 

    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'ä', 'ae')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'ö', 'oe')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'ü', 'ue')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'Ä', 'Ae')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'Ö', 'Oe')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'Ü', 'Ue')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'ß', 'ss')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'é', 'e')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'ê', 'e')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'à', 'a')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'è', 'e')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'i', 'i')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'l', 'l')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'L', 'l')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'd', 'd')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'ø', 'o')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, 'Þ', 'th')

    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, ' ', '-')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '/', '-')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '&', '-')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '%', '-')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, ',', '-')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, ';', '-')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, ':', '-')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '_', '-')

    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '+', '')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '.', '')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '""', '')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '*', '')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '<', '')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '>', '')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '?', '')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '‘', '')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '’', '')
    SELECT @Result = REPLACE(@Result, CHAR(39), '')

    WHILE CHARINDEX('--', @Result) > 0
    BEGIN    
        SET @Result = REPLACE(@Result, '--', '-')
    END    

    WHILE CHARINDEX('-', @Result) = 1
    BEGIN    
        SET @Result = RIGHT(@Result, LEN(@Result) - 1)
    END    

    WHILE LEN(@Result) > 0 AND SUBSTRING(@Result, LEN(@Result), 1) = '-'
    BEGIN
        SET @Result = LEFT(@Result, LEN(@Result) - 1)
    END

    RETURN @Result
END
GO

SELECT  dbo.MakeFriendlyURL('A,B & C Tyres')
```

This is primarily used as part of the import processes we roll out to our customers and as such it's implementation is RBAR which is less than ideal. But the function is used multiple times against multiple tables so I understand why it was developed like this originally., As the data sets have grown, this is becoming more of an issue.

Comment: SQL isn't meant for string manipulation. This conversion should be performed on the client's side using a language like C#. A SQLCLR function would be a lot faster too. BTW why are you converting UNICODE to ASCII with an unspecified codepage? Is this code trying to fix the use of an inappropriate type perhaps?

Comment: The replacements use *ASCII* literals too. There's no guarantee that `ø` will remain `ø` when you execute this code on a server with a different collation

Comment: If this were for a SQL Server 2017 then many of the REPLACEments could be done through a single [TRANSLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql) for the 1 character to 1 character replacements.

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for the comments.  There was an SQLCLR version of this before, but having to support this on Azure as well has made that route difficult. The codepage was standardised in the separate import routine that calls this.

Comment: I haven't played with 2017 much yet but will look into that. Wouldn't be able to implement that here but theres a redevelopment project happening along side this that might implement this approach. I'll have to look.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this would be a little more performant and easier to maintain.

By using a table variable, the sequence of replacements **seems** to keep correct.  I've yet to see an exception/failure.

If you use a table rather than a table variable, be sure to include a sequence number and order by.

**Example**

```
Declare @S nvarchar(max) = 'A,B & C Tyres'

Declare @MapValues table (MapFrom nvarchar(50),MapTo nvarchar(50))
Insert Into @MapValues values 
( 'ä', 'ae'),
( 'ö', 'oe'),
( 'ü', 'ue'),
( 'Ä', 'Ae'),
( 'Ö', 'Oe'),
( 'Ü', 'Ue'),
( 'ß', 'ss'),
( 'é', 'e'),
( 'ê', 'e'),
( 'à', 'a'),
( 'è', 'e'),
( 'i', 'i'),
( 'l', 'l'),
( 'L', 'l'),
( 'd', 'd'),
( 'ø', 'o'),
( 'Þ', 'th'),
( ' ', '-'),
( '/', '-'),
( '&', '-'),
( '%', '-'),
( ',', '-'),
( ';', '-'),
( ':', '-'),
( '_', '-'),
( '+', ''),
( '.', ''),
( '""', ''),
( '*', ''),
( '<', ''),
( '>', ''),
( '?', ''),
( '‘', ''),
( '’', ''),
( CHAR(39), ''),
-- Cleanup
( '-----', '-'),
( '----', '-'),
( '---', '-'),
( '--', '-'),
( '     ', '-'),
( '    ', '-'),
( '   ', '-'),
( '  ', '-')


Select @S=Replace(@S,MapFrom,MapTo)
 From  @MapValues

Select @S
```

**Returns**

```
A-B-C-Tyres
```

Comment: Didn't think of that as an option.  I'll give it a try and see how things stack up performance wise.  Will mark as answer with some test figures and my final solution.

Comment: @MatthewBaker Always interested in real-world benchmarks.

Comment: OK before I go any further got to say I love this piece of code - I think its a great way of doing it - a really elegant solution. Only problem is performance is terrible! Real world results - Applying to a table of  approx 7k rows - Original 1.485s - Your version 2.982s - Tweaked version (holding values in a table) 2.299s. Average figures over 100 like for like tests on a stand alone server.  I really wanted this to be the best answer, and I can't believe the mess in the original is actually quicker. Still a +1 for it being such nice code.

Comment: @MatthewBaker "One test is worth a thousand expert opinions"   Sorry you burned time on it, however, it can still be another tool in your box.  I use this technique to "tokenize" SQL and/or results like EMail content or stripping control characters.

Comment: No problem at all. As I said, i loved the code.  I’ll happily test a dozen options if it gets me where I need to be.  Many thanks again.